# SQL Conversion failed (Varchar to Int) when switching from selectbox to checkbox

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query i'm using to populate a select box with values that is storing to a field in my table set to (int).

The following works fine but my problem arises now because rather than just entering 1 option from a select box, I'd like to choose multiple values and save them into my table by switching to a checkbox grid.

TSQL for populating my dropdown:

```
Select CategoryName, CatID 
FROM mytableCategory
ORDER by CategoryName ASC
```

TSQL for insert:

```
INSERT INTO mytableListing
(CatID,Company,Doors,Address)
VALUES
('[CatID]','[Company]','[Doors]','[Address]')
```

How can I modify these statements to work with checkboxes rather than just a select box for the (CatID) field. CatID is int type on both the insert and reference table.

When simply changing my HTML from selectbox to checkbox it throws an error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3,4,35' to data type int.

Any help, examples, insight appreciated.

Comment: I think you may need to provide your code for insert, which you need to loop the _selection_ and insert record 1 by 1.  Try to provide your code and tag the language of your code.

Comment: Hello @Alex the code for insert is on my post.